# Query and list multi columns from many tables sharing same id

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have two tables:

- `OctSales` having *Account,Consumption,bill* columns.
- `NovSales` having *Account,Consumption,bill* columns.

I want to see the sales for the all accounts which are: appearing in any tables

[image: Example]

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Hint: `FULL JOIN`

Comment: A screen shot of text rather than a copy-and-paste of the text!?

Comment: Hint: don't use FULL JOIN

Comment: Sorry dears, this is my first question and I searched in hurry for the way to format may tables into text but I couldnt formate it correctly.

Comment: HoneyBadger Full join will compare Account from first table to the second table, however the second table contains addtional accounts not exist in first table. What I aim is to get the results of accounts from any table

Comment: That is exactly what a full join does. Maybe you are confused with inner join?

Comment: HoneyBadger. Can you suggest me simple query with full join so I can test it with the above info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this example for a `FULL JOIN` approach:

```
DECLARE @Oct AS TABLE (id INT, amount DECIMAL(15, 3))
DECLARE @Nov AS TABLE (id INT, amount DECIMAL(15, 3))

INSERT @Oct (id,    amount)
VALUES  ( 1, 35.4)
,       ( 2, 40)

INSERT @Nov (id,    amount)
VALUES  ( 1, 35.4)
,       ( 3, 80) 

SELECT  COALESCE(OCT.id, NOV.id) AS ID
,       SUM(OCT.amount) AS OCT_Amount
,       SUM(NOV.amount) AS NOV_Amount
FROM    @Oct AS OCT
FULL JOIN @Nov AS NOV
        ON  NOV.id = OCT.id
GROUP BY COALESCE(OCT.id, NOV.id)
```

Results in:

```
+----+------------+------------+
| ID | OCT_Amount | NOV_Amount |
+----+------------+------------+
|  1 | 35.400     | 35.400     |
|  2 | 40.000     | NULL       |
|  3 | NULL       | 80.000     |
+----+------------+------------+
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort, I have questions in your query. 1- In my situation I dont have to do the insert part since the tables I have are already have the data, correct?  2- Do I need to declare my tables and use them as table?

Comment: The table variables are only included to illustrate the method with data. In your case you would only need the structure of the actual select query.

Comment: Thanks million HoneyBadger, its finally worked for me